# 403 Forbidden, Tried everything

Tags: apache-httpd

So currently I am getting the 403 forbidden error. I have tried everything that I could possible think of. It was working a couple of days ago however it has stopped working now. I have tried everything from adding:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

Which is on all of my vhosts. Also I have tried chmod +x each of the sites main directory. So right now I am stumped, I have looked everywhere trying to figure out why it is happening.

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
```

Is what I am getting on every attempt to access one of the sites. I'm guessing this is what I expect from using an old PPC G5 mac as a server running YDL which I went ahead and compiled everything from source myself -.-

Comment: Did you try checking the error log?

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but you restarted Apache after changing the configuration, right?

Comment: Try to `su` to the apache user and attempt to `cd` to the directories in question or open one of the files in vi. If you're being blocked by file system permissions somewhere, that should help. Also check for SELinux (does YDL ship with SELinux?)

Comment: Firstly, quite clearly I have checked the error log since I mentioned it in the post, I have restarted apache. And when trying to su to the apache yeser i get `This account is currently not available.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue with an `Alias` entry I was using to include a directory into my server configuration.  I resolved the issue by sym-linking the directory into the correct place in the directory tree.

Do check the error log.

Some Linux distribution run the web server as `www-data`.  Verify which id is used and `sudo` to that account to check directory permissions.  It can help to have a file in the directory you can try to retrieve in case directory indexing is disabled.

Comment: Thanks this worked, strange though... I basically copied a virtualhost config from my test server to my ydl home server which worked fine on the test server but clearly not on my home server. Probably because my home 2.4 and the other is 2.2

Comment: Yes, I was upgrading to 2.4 when this happened.  Only one Alais failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check SElinux. That could be the culprit. To disable:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

You can also disable it via this file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Change the value from `enforced` to `disabled`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Disable selinux and check simply execute #setenforce 0 and also update the file /etc/sysconfig/selinux enforced to disabled